# Little o-notation. Difference between Linear term and error-term in differentiability.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have a concrete example for this. Let $f:\Bbb{R^n}\to\Bbb{R},$ s.t $f(x)=\langle a,x\rangle^2$ and $a\in\Bbb{R^n}.$ If we look at the differentiability ( at some arbitrary $x_0 \in \Bbb{R^n}$ ) of this function by definition, we will eventually end up with the following situation $$2\langle\langle a,x_0\rangle a,u\rangle+\langle a,u\rangle^2=L(u)+\vert\vert u\vert\vert\epsilon(u).$$

I claim that the derivative is $D_f(x_o)=L(u) = 2\langle\langle a,x_0\rangle a,u\rangle$, and that $\langle a,u\rangle^2=\epsilon(u)$, such that $\epsilon(u)\to 0$, as $u\to 0$. This is merely intuitive guessing on my part, since both of these terms tend to zero as $u$ tends to zero, and also both are linear.

In general, how can we in these situations differentiate between the error term $\epsilon (u)$, and the best linear approximation $L(u)=D_f$?

Comment: Sou you evaluate $f(x_0+u)-f(x_0)$ and write it as an expression such that $f(x_0+u)-f(x_0) = g(x) + h(x)$, where $g$ is linear. A necessary and sufficient cryteria to decide if $g=D_f(x_0)$ is to have $\lim_{x\to 0} h(x)/\|x\|=0$.

Comment: It's important to mention that we actually have $(D_f(x_0))(u)=L(u)$, for $D_f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$, where $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$ stands for the linear functions from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given  a point $x_0$ in the domain of $f$ and a variable increment vector $u$ attached at the point $x_0$. You then have computed
$$f(x_0+u)-f(x_0)=2\langle a, x_0\rangle\langle a, u\rangle+\langle a, u\rangle^2\ .$$
The part $$L(u):=2\langle a, x_0\rangle\langle a, u\rangle\tag{1}$$
is obviously linear in the increment variable $u$, and we have
$$f(x_0+u)-f(x_0)-L(u)=\langle a, u\rangle^2\ .$$
It follows that
$${|f(x_0+u)-f(x_0)-L(u)|\over |u|}={\langle a, u\rangle^2\over |u|}\leq |a|^2\>|u|\qquad(u\ne0)\ ,\tag{2}$$
by Schwarz' inequality. This shows that the LHS of $(2)$ converges to $0$ when $u\to0$ and proves (by definition of the total derivative) that $df(x_0)=L$,
where $L:\>{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}$  is given by $(1)$.